# focus() do JQuery no Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia,

Estou com um problema no firefox. Eu tenho um métodos que limpa um input com um valor que considero inválido ai na sequência dou focus para esse input. No Internet Explorer e no Chrome funciona.

O métodos que utilizo é esse:

```
$(".field-date").blur(function () {
    if (!DtValida(this.value)) {
        MsgAlerta("Data inválida.");           
        this.value = "";
        this.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;       
});
```

No Firefox limpa o input e mostra a mensagem, só o focus que não funciona mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, bom dia Kaique.
Pelo que eu pesquisei aqui existe um workaround para esse *issue*.
Tente aguardar o próximo "tick" para poder executar o focus.

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).focus();
    }, 0);
```

*UPDATE*

Vale a pena lembrar que dentro da função `setTimeout()` o `$(this)` tem um outro escopo, por tanto, é necessário focar no elemento selecionado.

Para isso, basta colocar exatamente o elemento:

```
setTimeout(function() {
            $(".field-date").focus();
        }, 0);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Andrew seria assim?  $(".field-time").blur(function () {
        if (!HorarioValido(this.value)) {
            MsgAlerta("Horário inválido.");
            this.value = "";

            setTimeout(function () {
                $(this).focus();
            }, 0);

            return false;

        }
        return true;
    });

Comment: Exato. Quando você coloca `setTimeout()` com valor 0, o JavaScript aguarda o loop event para executar a instrução depois. Faz o teste e me avisa.

Comment: Então testei o código que coloquei na resposta anterior, mudei pro setTimeout e funcionou para o IE e para o Chrome, porém para o Firefox ainda não funcionou.

Comment: Ao inves de `$(this).focus();`, coloque `$(".field-date").focus().` Aqui funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Deve ter algum script meu interferindo então, aqui ainda dois 3 navegadores o único que não funciona é firefox.

Comment: Kaique, você deve estar colocando de forma errada. Realmente se colocar apenas `this.focus()` ou `$(this).focus()` aqui também não funcionou. É um problema no Firefox. No entanto, colocar o selector ".field-date" funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou assim:

```
classe.blur(function () {
    var componente = $(this);

    if (!DtValida(this.value)) {
        MsgAlerta("Data inválida.");
        componente.val("");
        setTimeout(function () {
            componente.focus();
        });
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Eu tinha tentado com o setTimeout anteriormente e não funcionou ai tirei o último parâmetro o do intervalo ai funcionou, não entendi bem o que isso muda vou pesquisar melhor.

Sobre usar o seletor com a classe me gerou um problema porque tenho mais de um elemento com essa classe, ai o focus ia sempre para o ultimo. Ai busquei novamente o seletor ao invés de usar o this direto graças a dica de escopo no update do Andrew.

Obrigado pela ajuda Andrew.